# select2 too long list without scroll makes wrong item selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I have select2 attached to select field. We have about 20-30 items to choose from. Items represented as long strings (2-3 lines in each). So we need to scroll to select items after 15th.

So:

1. We click on select2 to trigger dropdown.
2. We scroll whole page to access one of the latter elements.
3. We select 25th element for example.
4. But select now has 17th element as its value. And this is totally wrong.

I can't think about any workaround, but to make select2 fit in page height entirely. And only one solution is to make it scrollable, but this is ugly. So, is there any other solution ?

I'm removing scroll from select2 results by this css

```
.select2-results {
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: none;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/s3mrq/10/

Comment: For me, a container with scrollbar is way better/easier than scrolling the whole page 100 times for an element. I looked at the select2 code. It seems that they using ```mousedown``` events for closing and ```mouseup``` and ```click``` for selection. If you really want a dropdown without scrollbar you'll have to edit the select2 code.

Comment: We have big project, and its style should be homogeneous, so I need to use dropdowns without scroll.

Comment: how about using the paging feature?  put the items into an ajax call and then return them 10 at a time with automatic scrolling by select2 when you reach the bottom of the list?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question, but it seems like you might be after a good way to display a lot of elements in a dropdown with the ease of [Select2](https://select2.github.io) but the ability to see lots of options at once that you might get from a custom-styled `<select>`. If that's the case, a plugin I wrote ([maximize-select2-height](https://github.com/panorama-ed/maximize-select2-height)) that expands Select2 dropdowns to be larger might be what you're looking for. Let me know if that helps!